# why filtrated array provides only 1 element not arrays of elements Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have the issue: I need to filter arrays with unrelated fields where stops id based on routes id. So i created the empty array and trying to filter items using **where** method. But now it dosen't work and gives me only one element from the array. I use print and it says: I`/flutter (16814): [Instance of 'Stop']`

As O know when i use `initState()`I should to put this line   `filteredStops = stop.where((element) => element.stId == stId).toList();` inside `initState()`, but i use FutureProvider. How can I solve it?

What should I do to resolve my issue? I really get stuck and don't get what am I doing wrong?

My firts page, when user taps on

```
  onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => Stops(
                               stId: routes[index].mrId,
                                stTitle: routes[index].mrTitle,
                              )));
                    },
```

the second page where everything should be filtered:

```
class Stops extends StatelessWidget {
  final int stId;
  final String stTitle;
  Stops({Key key,  this.stId, this.stTitle }) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Stop> stop = Provider.of<List<Stop>>(context).where((element) => element.stId == stId).toList();
    List <Stop> filteredStops = [];
    filteredStops = stop.where((element) => element.stId == stId).toList();
   print(stop);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Bus Stops'),
      ),
      body: (filteredStops == null)
          ? Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      )
          : ListView.builder(
        itemCount: filteredStops.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(filteredStops[index].stId.toString()),
          );
        },

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The models I wanted to filter:

```
class Routes {
  Routes({
    this.mrId,
    this.mrNum,
    this.mrTitle,
    this.mrNote,
    this.ttId,
    this.mtId,
  });
  @HiveField(0)
  final int mrId;
  @HiveField(1)
  final String mrNum;
  @HiveField(2)
  final String mrTitle;
  @HiveField(3)
  final String mrNote;

class Stop extends ChangeNotifier{
  Stop({
    this.stId,
    this.okId,
    this.srId,
    this.stTitle,
    this.stDesc,
    this.stLat,
    this.stLong,
    this.stNote,
  });

  final int stId;
  final String okId;
  final int srId;
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to achieve. Could you either rephrase your question or give an example?

Comment: Hi @wxker I want to filter two models by ids but they don't related to each others by common id: filter stop id based on routes id.  So i was advised that I should create the third  array where I want to put the filtered by id data. So i did everything like that, but when I try to do this with Provider package It returns me the only single item from array.  I put models what I am talking about in my question

Comment: I guess you are wrongly using the `Provider`. It is not supposed to call within the `@build` method. So please have a look at the Provider documentation https://pub.dev/packages/provider